# Error in Spyder console when printing

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, spyder

I have this problem with `Spyder(in Windows 10)`. When I try to do anything on my `spyder` console (even something as simple as 1+1), I get the following error message in the internal console tab:

(Any help will be appreciated)

```
Traceback (most recent call last): <br> <br>
  File "C:\Users\ JohnDoe \Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\qtconsole\base_frontend_mixin.py", line 163, in _dispatch<br><br>
Traceback (most recent call last):<br><br>
  File "C:\Users\ JohnDoe \Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\qtconsole\base_frontend_mixin.py", line 163, in _dispatch<br><br>
    handler(msg)<br><br>
  File "C:\Users\JohnDoe\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\widgets\ipythonconsole\namespacebrowser.py", line 188, in _handle_execute_reply<br><br>
    self.handle_exec_method(msg)<br><br>
  File "C:\Users\ JohnDoe\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\widgets\ipythonconsole\shell.py", line 225, in handle_exec_method<br><br>
    properties = ast.literal_eval(data['text/plain'])<br><br>
KeyError: 'text/plain'<br><br>
    handler(msg)<br><br>
  File "C:\Users\ JohnDoe\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\widgets\ipythonconsole\namespacebrowser.py", line 188, in _handle_execute_reply<br><br>
    self.handle_exec_method(msg)<br><br>
  File "C:\Users\ JohnDoe\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\widgets\ipythonconsole\shell.py", line 222, in handle_exec_method<br><br>
    view = ast.literal_eval(data['text/plain'])<br><br>
KeyError: 'text/plain'
```

Comment: This error was fixed in Spyder 3.0.2. Please update to that version.

Comment: That's what I did.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem gets resolved when you install Spyder 3 like Carlos [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40434824/error-in-spyder-console-when-printing/41548814#comment68819101_40434824)

> This error was fixed in Spyder 3.0.2. Please update to that version.

However, it actually does not impacts my codes or run times. The only drawback is that you cannot test your codes out on the machines which shows this error.

Comment: We added further validations to avoid this problem in Spyder 3.1, in case you want to update to that version :-)

Comment: Thanks Carlos. I did. :) Much appreciated.